# How to "calculate performant wise" cumulative sum column in sql

Tags: sql

Hi lets say i have a table that contains cost per day

and i want by the end of the month to calculate that cumulative sum for that day
so if for say we have those values: 1,2,3 (per 3 days)
we we'll calculate 1,(1+2)=3, (1+2+3)=6 (for the last day)

i wonder how we can do it through sql without sorting the days (n*lgn) cost

is there any other way to solve it?

sample data :

```
1/1,  1
2,1, 10
3/,  12
```

desired result (with total from start of the month):

```
1/1,  1,  1
2,1, 10, 11
3/,  12, 23
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a rolling sum.

```
select *
, sum(cost_column) over (order by day_column asc) as rolling_cost
from yourtable
```

| day_column | cost_column | rolling_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-1-2 | 10 | 11 |
| 2022-1-3 | 12 | 23 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4a762efee5fd48187b369057e5ba5eea)*